# Gatsby build getting window error while using onLoad

Tags: reactjs, build, window, gatsby

In my code im trying to get the div height by clientHeight by using onLoad. ComponentDdiMount doesnt give the clientHeight in this case as images load in the div.The code works fine for me.But when i try gatsby build i get the window error as im using onLoad. Is there any workaround for this?

```
    export default class Mainpageanimation extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.topref = React.createRef();
      }
      load = () =>{ 
       const centerheight = this.topref.current.clientHeight;
       //animate div
      }
     render(){
       return (
         <div className="topdiv" ><img src={require("image.png") } ref={this.topref}  onLoad= 
    {this.load}/></div>
      );
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including onLoad property only when the code is running in the browser

```
export default class Mainpageanimation extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.topref = React.createRef();
      }
      load = () =>{ 
       const centerheight = this.topref.current.clientHeight;
       //animate div
      }
     render(){
       return (
         <div 
            className="topdiv" >
            <img src={require("image.png") } ref={this.topref}  
            {...typeof window !== 'undefined' ? {onLoad: this.load} : {}}
            />
         </div>
      );
    }
   }
```

Comment: This code breaks. `<img>` is not properly self-closed and in terms of clarity, readability and cleaning of code maybe is not the best approach since JSX should avoid that kind of logic if it can be managed by a function itself.

Answer (score 0):

With `gatsby build`, rather than `gatsby develop`, some objects such as `window` or `document` are not defined at the point your code is requesting them. The usual errors are fixed by checking if the window is defined in a `componentDidMount` lifecycle/`useEffect` hook before triggering your function. From [Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/):

> Some of your code references “browser globals” like `window` or
> `document`. If this is your problem you should see an error above like
> “`window` is not defined”. To fix this, find the offending code and
> either a) check before calling the code if `window` is defined so the
> code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or
> b) if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, move
> that code into a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or into a `useEffect` hook,
> which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser.

So, my first approach will be checking if the `window` is defined:

```
  load = () =>{ 
    let centerHeight;
    if (typeof window !== undefined){
       centerHeight= this.topref.current.clientHeight;
      //animate div
    }
  }
```

If this doesn't work, I would try to change your onLoad function and use it in a `componentDidMount` directly:

```
    export default class Mainpageanimation extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.topref = React.createRef();
      }
      componentDidMount(){
         let centerHeight;
         if (typeof window !== undefined){
          centerHeight= this.topref.current.clientHeight;
          //animate div
         }
      }

     render(){
       return (
         <div className="topdiv" ><img src={require("image.png") } ref={this.topref} /></div>
      );
    }
   }
```

---

Besides the answer, I think you should bind your reference. In a functional component arrow functions does it automatically but in a stateful component like yours, you must do it manually. In your constructor:

```
this.topref= this.topref.bind(this);
```

You can check for further information in [Refs and the DOM by React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).